# How to click a hyperlink embedded in an anchor tag of a html using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript

I am able to open a browser and the page I want to work with. But the actual point of interest is the link called "Next". I want to click on that link but I tried unsuccessfully to get that element in my code. Here is what I have done so far.

```
Dim URL
Dim IE
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")
URL = "http://mylink.com/"
IE.Visible = True
IE.Navigate URL 

Dim a
Set a = IE.Document.GetElementsByTagName("arrowRight")

For i = 0 To a.Length - 1
    MsgBox "Found it"
    a.Click
    Exit For  
Next
```

This is how the "Next" hyperlink is embedded in the page code:

```
<a class="arrowRight" href="http://SomeURL.com/150.html">Next</a>
```

Comment: SO is not a place where other people write code for you. What have you tried so far, and what *specific* problem do you need help with?

Comment: Hello Ansgar! HA! My apologies but I definitely was not expecting a full version of the code and my sorry again if that is what my earlier post conveyed. Anyway, here is what I came up with from searching AFTER I posted my original question. Although what I am about to post is different what I have asked in the post above, I can build on it once I get thru this problem. Anyway I am having trouble with a specific element on the page that does not have an ID. I am afraid I ran out of character limit on this comment, so let me show you the code in the following comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arrowRight` is a (CSS) class name, not a tag name, so you need to check for `a` tags with a class `arrowRight`:

```
For Each a In ie.document.getElementsByTagName("a")
  If a.getAttribute("class") = "arrowRight" And a.innerText = "Next" Then
    a.Click
    Exit For
  End If
Next
```

Comment: Can't upvote (apparently I have to have 15 reps). So, great solution. Works well. But for some reason, a.innerText fails. So, I had to remove it. Also, I think I will have to add some sleep time before the loop because, if the page does not load by the time the cursor is on for loop, it fails. Still thanks!